# What should CFBuldneURLIconFile size be?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, info.plist

What should the size of the icon supplied for `CFBuldneURLIconFile` be?

I'm *guessing* 57x57 and that having an @2x version present will automatically be loaded where appropriate, but can't find documentation anywhere (Googling 'CFBuldneURLIconFile' returns nothing!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean CFBundleIconFile? (Must confess I've never heard of "CFBuldneURLIconFile" - where does this come from?)

Irrespective, there's an Apple Q&A document entitled "[How are the icon files in my application bundle used on iPad and iPhone?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html)" that lists all of the relevant icon sizes/default filenames, which should tell you what you need to know.

Irrespective, the default sizes/names are 57x57 ("Icon.png") for the non retina/iPad devices, 114x114 ("Icon@2x.png") for retina devices and 72x72 ("Icon-72.png") for the iPad, if that's relevant.

**UPDATE**

Think I might have found what you're after. The [Information Property List Key Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW9) doc contains information about the `CFBundleURLTypes`, which states that it's effectively the URL equivalent of the CFBundleDocumentTypes. As such, you can presumably use the icon sizes it lists [within that part of the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW9). (See the "Document Icons" section.)

Comment: No, CFBundleIconFile is well documented. CFBundleIconFile is different: it's an optional part of the specification of a custom URL, under CFBuldleURLTypes.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Ahh, I *think* see what you're after now. I've updated my answer - hopefully this is what you're after.

Comment: Thanks, I think that might be it, but it's still not clear to me from that how to specify which icon is which.